# Firebird Java: GDS Exception. 335544421. connection rejected by remote interface

Tags: java, macos, firebird

I am trying to rework a legacy application...

I have downloaded and installed: **FirebirdCS-2.5.7-27050-x86_64.pkg**

I have set up the following:
**export FIREBIRD_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources
export PATH=$PATH:$FIREBIRD_HOME/bin**

I have used the following to test the installation:

```
$ isql 
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
SQL> quit;
```

I can use isql to connect to a database and I can show the tables and select data from them:

```
$ isql -user sysdba -password masterkey
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
SQL> connect employee;
Database:  employee, User: sysdba
SQL> show tables;
   COUNTRY                                CUSTOMER                       
   DEPARTMENT                             EMPLOYEE                       
   EMPLOYEE_PROJECT                       JOB                            
   PROJECT                                PROJ_DEPT_BUDGET               
   SALARY_HISTORY                         SALES                          
SQL> quit;
```

**I can backup table using gbak too, so it appears that the installation of Firebird is good.**

But when I try to connect to the **employee** database using **Java**, I get an exception with the following error message:

```
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544421. connection rejected by remote interface
```

The Java code:

```
try
{
  Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:3050//Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/examples/empbuild/employee.fdb", "sysdba", "masterkey");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tried many variations on the 'connection string', they all produce errors, so that is **NOT** the problem.

I am using the following jar:

```
**jaybird-full-2.1.6.jar**
```

I am using Eclipse Helios, Java 1.6 and I am using OSX on a Mac.

Is the jar the wrong version?

What else could it be?

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: U make connections with different connections strings. That can not be compared! What would say `isql` on command copied from Java?  `SQL> connect localhost:3050//Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/examples/empbuild/employee.fdb;` ? what would Java say on command copied from isql `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/employee")`?

Comment: `jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:3050//Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/examples/empbuild/employee.fdb` is malformed connection string. See pages 9 and 10 at https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/Jaybird_2_1_JDBC_driver_manual.pdf

Comment: I have tried many combinations and I am fairly certain that that is not the cause of this problem. I just tried your suggestion: jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/empl‌​oyee and it produces the same error message. So thanks but the problem is not solved...

Comment: I tried this and many other combinations. None work:-       connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/examples/empbuild/employee.fdb", "sysdba", "masterkey");

Comment: Mark, I have upgraded to Java 7 and jaybird 3.0.2. Now I get: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". [SQLState:08006, ISC error code:335544721].

Comment: That error would suggest that Firebird server is not actually running (or at least not on port 3050), under some cases ISQL can also use an embedded or local connection. What happens in ISQL if you use `connect 'localhost:employee'`? Alternatively, try specifying 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, maybe you run into a problem with the lack of IPv6 support in Firebird 2.5 and earlier.

Comment: ...or some antivirus/firewall just blocks Java VM attempts at making TCP 3050 connections. It is a pity, the topicstarter avoids trying ISQL with the connection string made after the Java app...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your JDBC URL is invalid because you are combining two incompatible syntaxes for the Jaybird URL in a way that will not work. The correct URL is:

```
"jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050//Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/examples/empbuild/employee.fdb"
```

Note that this might still fail, because it is entirely possible that connecting using this path is disallowed in the Firebird config.

With the URL in your question you are actually trying to connect to a database on the relative path `3050//Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/examples/empbuild/employee.fdb` (relative to the Firebird install or some other config-dependent location).

The fact that you can use `connect employee` from ISQL, suggest that it would be possible for you to instead use the connection URL with an alias:

```
"jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/employee"
```

or even shorter (as port 3050 is the default):

```
"jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/employee"
```

See also [JDBC URLs in the Jaybird FAQ](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#jdbc-urls-java.sql.drivermanager).

I strongly suggest that you use an alias (as above using `employee`) to connect to your database, and that you put your real databases outside the `/Library/Frameworks` folder.

And you really need to update your Jaybird version, Jaybird 2.1.6 is 9 years old. The latest version is 3.0.2, or - if you are stuck on Java 6 - 2.2.13, see [JDBC driver downloads on firebirdsql.org](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/).

Disclosure: I am one of the developers of Jaybird.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark, I've seen several of your posts and have followed them in trying to solve this problem. Unfortunately, your suggestions return the same error. Strangely, as I try different connections, I sometimes get: Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". BTW, I am not restricted to Java 6, it's just legacy code. Also, I think I would have to backup and restore my databases to go up to Firebird 3, is that correct? And I remember that I really liked the Firebird database back when I had it working...

Comment: @Lyndon Jaybird 3 does not mean you need to use Firebird 3. Jaybird 3 supports Firebird 2.0 and later (and technically works on Firebird 1.0 and later, but that is no longer 'officially' not supported). In any case, if this didn't solve it (and I assume you tried to upgrade Jaybird to 2.2.x or 3.0.x as well), then I suggest you post a message to the Firebird-Java mailinglist, as Stack Overflow is not really a suitable venue for troubleshooting.

Comment: I realise that Mark, I am on Firebird 2.5 but now using jaybird 3.0.2 for idk 1.7. Now when I run I get: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". [SQLState:08006, ISC error code:335544721]. I will try the Firebird-Java mailing list too. It's strange because in the past, Firebird was easy to connect to and use, it was one of the things I liked about it...

Comment: check antiviruses and firewalls. Run some sniffer like MS Network Monitor or WireShark and ensure JVM can open connections to 3050 port and fbserver can listen and accept them.

Answer (score 0):

Unlock the port 3050 on Windows Firewall.